# Infinite loop on a simple list for two predicates

Tags: haskell

When i try to compile this line :
`mult y = [x*2 | x <- [1..], x <= y]`

And run it, I have an infinite loop that I must cancel with CTRL + C

`*Main> mult 10`

`[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20`

Do you know why those predicate are not correctly interpreted ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for

```
mult y = [x * 2 | x <- [1..y]]
```

In this version, the `[1..y]` gets compiled to a finite list from `1` up to `y`. In your original code

```
mult y = [x * 2 | x <- [1..], x <= y]
```

Haskell doesn't understand complicated concepts like the nature of `<=` as an ordering or that `[1..]` is a monotonic list. So Haskell is determined to come up with every natural number, just to make sure some really big number out there doesn't happen to be less than `y`, by some fluke. You and I can look at that code and see that it obviously won't find any, but Haskell doesn't understand that, so it goes looking anyway.